# Generate Random number for WordPress for Human Check

Tags: php, wordpress, random

I have a Custom Form and wanted to secure the Form submission with Human Check, by asking visitors to enter the given Random Number to validate.

Below is the function to generate a Random number:

```
function random_number() {
    $rand1 = rand(10, 100);
    $rand2 = rand(10, 100);
    $randnum = $rand1 * $rand2;
return $randnum;
}
```

Below is the **Validation Form** the Human Check:

```
<label for="humanCheck">
    <?php echo random_number(); ?>
</label>
<input id="humanCheck" type="number" name="message_human" placeholder="Enter above number">
```

Below is the **Validation Code** to check whether visitor entered the given random number:

```
$randomnumbercheck = echo random_number();
if (!$human == 0) {
if ($human != $randomnumbercheck) {
    response("error", $not_human); //not human!
} else {
/// form submission
}
```

Problem is random numbers generated by the `random_number()` function in both Validation form & validation code are different and it is always a false validation.

Comment: I think this kind of authenticating can be easily bypassed.Because the number is actually given in context and can be read by bot and re-entered as well ! I suggest not using this method since it doesn't do much about making the number somehow that could be hard for bot to read it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating using entering a number which is given in the context is NOT a good way!

It's not that simple to authenticate safely using just a confirmation number! You have to confirm it server side.But in this example, the user can resend and resend and again and again the same data and it will be confirmed! To prevent this, you have to make a table and insert records in it.By the way it's just the code you wanted :

```
<?php

function random_number() {
    $rand1 = rand(10, 100);
    $rand2 = rand(10, 100);
    $randnum = $rand1 * $rand2;
return $randnum;
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   $randomnumbercheck =$_POST['hidden'];
   $human=$_POST['message_human'];

if ($human !== $randomnumbercheck) {
    echo "error";
} else {
echo "Correct! <br/>";
}




}else{echo "no post";}
$generatednumber=random_number();
?>
<label for="humanCheck">
   <?=$generatednumber;?>
</label>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input id="humanCheck" type="input" name="message_human" placeholder="Enter above number"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?=$generatednumber;?>"/>
</form>
```